# MYSQL Merging Two Result Rows - (Losing and Winning Teams) into one column

Tags: mysql, union

I have four columns, that i want to merge as follows, grouped by year, game_dt

```
  GAME_DT     YEAR    WIN    LOSS
  -------------------------------
  20040804    2004    NYN   MIL
  20040804    2004    MIN   ANA
  20040804    2004    NYA   OAK
```

Output

```
  GAME_DT     YEAR  TEAM   RESULT
  --------------------------------
  20040804    2004    NYN   W
  20040804    2004    MIL   L
  20040804    2004    MIN   W
  20040804    2004    ANA   L
  20040804    2004    NYA   W
  20040804    2004    OAK   L
```

**UPDATE:**
my code as followed by Nitin:

```
 **

    SELECT 
    GAME_DT,GAME_ID,
    YEAR_ID, 
    if(home_score_ct>away_score_ct,home_team_id,away_team_id) as Team, 
    'W' as result
FROM 
    games 
UNION 
SELECT 
    GAME_DT,game_id,
    YEAR_id, 
    if(home_score_ct<away_score_ct,home_team_id,away_team_id) as Team, 
    'L' as result
FROM 
    games
     group by year_id,game_dt,game_id,result
     order by game_dt,game_id
```

This is working! Thank you Nitin for getting me going in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get result using UNION.

```
SELECT 
    GAME_DT, 
    YEARS, 
    WIN, 
    'W' 
FROM 
    game_dt 
UNION 
SELECT 
    GAME_DT, 
    YEARS, 
    LOSS, 
    'L' 
FROM 
    game_dt
```

Comment: Thank you...working like a charm with the right 'group by'

Answer (score 0):

Please write down the query sql,In order to find the problem